# What is the right way to indent your source code?

Tags: best-practices, editors, source

This is probably a really basic question:

When I write code, I want to achieve a logical and readable structure of the lines, where I can see which brace closes which brace.

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{multlined}
  Here is some random equation that goes on for a long time
 \end{multlined}
\end{equation}
```

If the equation (here I am referring to the source code, not the compiled document) goes on to where it needs to jump to the next line, it is left-aligned, which screws up the indentation. I can manually add some spaces, but then if I change the size of the window, it realigns and is wrong again. What is the right way to achieve a logical indentation?

My apologies if this has been asked before; I did not find it on previously asked questions.

**Edit:** Sorry, forgot to mention, I am using writelatex.com as my editor.

Comment: This appears to be entirely a question about the editor you are using, but you have not said what that is.

Comment: Many text editors (not sure about LaTeX-specific editors) will allow you to wrap at a certain number of characters regardless of window width.  That may help you if you like using manual indents on continued lines.  I prefer not to, and switch word wrap on and off frequently.

Comment: I rarely use code indentation other than in macro definitions. Indenting environments' contents seems to me making the document *less* readable, but that's how I'm used to.

Comment: Why to worry when there is cmhughes and his `latexindent` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I actually ponder this question often, and haven't yet (after decades) settled on a single approach that works universally.  And as you see from your comments, each coder has their own "style" of indentation.

I agree with egreg that it is most important in macro definitions.  One method that I have found particularly useful, if you have to break up the macro name from its argument across multiple lines, is to end the prior line with `{%` and indent the next line:

```
\...\macroname{%
  \argument}%
\next code line
```

as opposed to

```
\...\macroname%
  {\argument}%
\next code line
```

The former tells me that `\argument` is, in fact, an argument of `\macroname` and not the next macro in the sequence of commands. You might say that the braces already tell you that, but you wouldn't know that until your eyes got to that line.  With the former approach (opening brace), its like putting a comma at the end of a line of text, and not at the beginning of the next line.

If there are multiple arguments, or if the argument itself is long and complex, perhaps requiring multiple lines itself, I will often close out the argument in a symmetric way with the calling macro:

```
\...\macroname{%
  \argument{blah}{blah}\other-parts-of argument{}%
}%
\next code line
```

And if things get really hairy, I will sometimes start and end the argument braces on lines by themselves:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\a}{\b}}%
  {&
    true condition%
  }{%
    false condition%
  }%
 next line of code
```

The `}{%` construct, on a line by itself, I find particularly helpful in reminding me that one argument is closing out and the next argument is opening.

As you can see, one could say that my method is not consistent, but varies with the complexity of what is being coded.

And I would reiterate that the goal is readability and understandability.  If parsing your code a certain way helps the reader get the gist of your intent, then the parse is helpful.  As in all things, there are unique approaches and styles.

Comment: you can also use `{%}` for always remembering to remove the whitespace which is also easy to distinguish the open braces.

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure I understand your comment...perhaps I'm on the verge of learning something :^)  Could you elaborate?

Comment: the closing brace is ignored becayse it becomes a comment and you can spot the open braces easier.  well my preference maybe

Comment: @percusse I think I understand.  Are you saying you use `{%}` and `}%{` on different lines as visual clues in the midst of long definition?  I think I can see how that would work.

Comment: Precisely though I don't use the closing one.